# How to use Less and Omega theme together in a right way?

Tags: theming

I know there is a similar question [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15216/how-to-add-less-files-to-omega-html5-subtheme) and I don't mean duplicate. But I have the problem that @ril44 posted in that question.

> Using stylesheets[all][] = example.css.less is problematic. This
>   usage, while >generally correct, causes example.css.less to load
>   before Omega's stylesheets.

I'm using the method (but not working...)

- Create global.css.less in your theme's css folder (important!).
- Create a stanza like this in your theme.info file:

```
    css[global.css.less][name] = My Project styles
    css[global.css.less][description] = LESS CSS stylesheet for My Project.
    css[global.css.less][options][weight] = 10
    settings[alpha_css][global.css.less] = 'global.css.less'
```

Comment: Did you enable the global.css.less file in the Omega admin? (http://drupal.org/node/928292#comment-5338648)

Comment: @sheena_d That would be an answer.